# Coloring labels using scatterplot3d in R

Tags: r, visualization

I am trying to visualize data using R and scatterplot3d.

I have loaded data and used:

```
colors <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9" )
scatterplot3d(output$X2,output$X6 , output$X7 , color=colors, pch="X9")
```

X9 is label column in my dataset. it contains 3 categories : A , B , C.

By documentation:

> color : colors of points in the plot, optional if x is an appropriate
>   structure. Will be ignored if highlight.3d = TRUE.
>
> pch: plotting  "character", i.e. symbol to use.

Yet I still get this error

> Error in scatterplot3d(output\$X2, output\$X6, output\$X7, color =
>   colors,  :    length(color) must be equal length(x) or 1

I assumed I had to put color for every collumn in dataset, but creating such array where:

```
length( colors ) = length( num of columns )
```

yields the same error.

What is the right way to add colors?

Answer (score 0):

For the `colors`  argument you need to assign a vector with the same length as your data points.

You don't explain how colors must be assigned to values of your output columms . In any regard, this would assign 4 different colors randomly:

```
cols = sample(1:4, nrow(output), replace=TRUE)
```

plot it with

```
scatterplot3d(output$X2,output$X6 , output$X7 , color=cols, pch=19, cex=1)
```

You could create a new column in your dataframe, e.g. `rgbcolor` and assign that:

```
scatterplot3d(output$X2,output$X6 , output$X7 , color=output$rgbcolor, pch=19, cex=1)
```

`pch` is the plotting character id, usually 1, 19 or 20 (circle or larger dot or smaller dot. (see for yourself: `plot(1:25, 1:25, pch=1:25)`)

Tune the `cex` param to make it larger or smaller (1 means size = 100%)